# select as DML Command

Tags: sql, oracle

I know for a fact that select is dml command because of

`select * into new_table from old_table`

in SQL server how can i write equivalent query in oracle for showing select is a dml operation.

Comment: The equivalent in standard SQL (and Oracle) for that statement would be `create table new_table as select * from old_table` which is clearly **not** a DML statement (but a DDL statement). However `select` on it's own **is** a DML statement, not a DDL statement.

Comment: A statement that _creates_  a new table is always DDL - no matter what the keyword is that starts the statement.

Comment: If you have NEW_TABLE already created (ad it has the same structure), then `insert into NEW_TABLE select * from OLD_TABLE` is probably what you want. It is purely DML statement (it is sometimes referred as IAS, and code mentioned by @a_horse_with_no_name as CTAS)

Comment: so can you give an example how select is used as dml in oracle?

Comment: `select` ***is*** a DML statement. An example would be `select 42 from dual`

Comment: @San: that's not true. A temporary table will only be created if the table name is prefixed with `#` (or `##`). If no such prefix is used for the name, SQL Server **will** create a permanent table (assuming the statement is committed properly)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Oops... You are right, I overlooked that there is no #, thanks for correction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SELECT` is a Data Manipulation Language (DML) statement according to the [Oracle SQL Language Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_1001.htm#SQLRF30042):

> The SELECT statement is a limited form of DML statement in that it can
>   only access data in the database. It cannot manipulate data stored in
>   the database, although it can manipulate the accessed data before
>   returning the results of the query.

It's common to colloquially treat `SELECT` as separate from DML because in practice they generally do different things; `SELECT` reads data and DML writes data.  But there are some important cases where a `SELECT` statement can act like DML:

- `SELECT some_function() FROM DUAL;` This `SELECT` calls a function that could potentially change data.  This is usually a bad idea, but it's possible if the function is created with `PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS TRANSACTION;`.
- `SELECT * FROM TABLE FOR UPDATE;` This `SELECT` locks rows in the table and starts a transaction.  It doesn't change any data but it can certainly affect other processes that
  are trying to modify data.

---

Also, per the [Oracle manual](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_1001.htm#SQLRF30001) there are **six** types of statements:

1. Data Definition Language (DDL) Statements

   ```
   ADMINISTER KEY MANAGEMENT, ALTER (except ALTER SESSION and ALTER SYSTEM),
   ANALYZE,ASSOCIATE STATISTICS,AUDIT,COMMENT,CREATE,DISASSOCIATE STATISTICS,
   DROP,FLASHBACK,GRANT,NOAUDIT,PURGE,RENAME,REVOKE,TRUNCATE
   ```
2. Data Manipulation Language (DML) Statements

   ```
   CALL,DELETE,EXPLAIN PLAN,INSERT,LOCK TABLE,MERGE,SELECT,UPDATE
   ```
3. Transaction Control Statements

   ```
   COMMIT,ROLLBACK,SAVEPOINT,SET TRANSACTION,SET CONSTRAINT
   ```
4. Session Control Statements

   ```
   ALTER SESSION,SET ROLE
   ```
5. System Control Statement

   ```
   ALTER SYSTEM
   ```
6. Embedded SQL Statements

   ```
   SQL statements inside a procedural language program.
   ```

If you want to fully classify a SQL statement programmatically, like I've done in [this program](https://github.com/jonheller1/plsql_lexer/blob/master/statement_classifier.plsql),
 then "Embedded SQL Statements" doesn't make much sense and almost nobody uses them anymore.  And in practice it would be useful to have an additional category for

7. PL/SQL

   ```
   Statements run through anonymous blocks.
   ```

Although SQL and PL/SQL are not the same thing, in practice they can both be treated as types of statements since they can both be executed in the same contexts. Especially with 12c, where PL/SQL and SQL can be embedded in each other.

Answer (score 0):

Database operations can be categorized into three:

1. DDL (Data Definition Language). It is typically used to create tables, indexes, views etc.
2. DML (Data Manipulation language). As name suggests the commands are typically used to insert, update or delete the data from existing tables.
3. SQL (Structured Query Language). It is primarily used to query the tables
4. Also there is 4th one called DCL (Data Control Language). It is primarily to grant and revoke permissions.

Also theoretically DDL, DML and DCL are considered to be subset of SQL.

If the old table and new table already exists and structures are same, then you can use `insert into new_table select * from old_table`.

If the table does not exists, you can use CTAS - `create table new_table as select * from old_table`

Comment: SQL is the whole language, DDL and DML are subset of SQL

Comment: The full name of the Microsoft DB server is Microsoft SQL Server I see no confusion with it, also `SELECT` can is sometimes put in the DML, sometimes put by itself as DQL (Data Query Language)

Comment: My question was _select is a DML command. why so?_ . It is mentioned as the same in almost all the SQL documentations.

Comment: I need a justification

Comment: No typical select is not DML command, unless it is inserting data. For example in Oracle, you can run `insert into new_table select * from old_table`. It is DML command because it is inserting into a table. It is also using select query to fetch the data from old table.

Comment: I'm not the one that created those acronyms, nor the one that divided SQL into DML, DDL, DCL and TCL (Transactional Control Language), IMHO there is no need for any of this, I simply pointed out that, depending on the definition, sometimes `SELECT` is deemed part, of DML, for example [Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/sqlplsql.htm#i18503) put `SELECT` in the DML.

Comment: Also the M in DML stands for Manipulation not Modification

Comment: Yes, I typed while walking :)